# Accessing GUI components through C++ code in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have created a Windows Form Project in VC++ 2010 Express version. So, in that project I created a Form, which had only 1 button and 1 textbox. The name of this form was `Form1`.

This button called a function `FD` written in a `.cpp` file in the same project. However, while running the code, I need to update the textbox with some text. I want to access the textbox through the `.cpp` file.

I have tried the following:
I included `#include "Form1.h"` and then wrote `textBox1->Text="XYZ"`. However, while building it says that it cannot find any member called `textBox1`.

How do I access the textbox from the `.cpp` file?

EDIT:
`FD.cpp`

```
#include<stdafx.h>
#include "Form1.h" 
... //other includes  

void abc()
{
    //Some code
    textBox1->Text="String to be displayed."
    //Some code
}
```

`Form1.h`
This is simple GUI form, where a button called `button1` and a textbox called `textBox1` is added.

```
#include<FD.h>
//code generated by the GUI
void button1_click()
{
    abc();
}
```

Comment: Did you use win API or MFC?

Comment: Pass Form1^ reference to the method as parameter.

Comment: did you tried textBox1.Text="XYZ";

Comment: @AliKazmi, I did try that. It doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexFarber, I dunno how to pass Form1 by reference. Could you please give me some sample code?

Comment: @SHR I think I used the winAPI.

Comment: The code is too long to be shared. I'll edit the question to include what I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// FD.cpp
void abc(Form1^ f)
{
    // Assuming that textBox1 is public. If not, make it public or make
    // public get property
    f->textBox1->Text="String to be displayed."
    //Some code
}

// Form1.h
void button1_click()
{
    abc(this);
}
```

Or:

```
// FD.cpp
void abc(TextBox^ t)
{
    t->Text="String to be displayed."
    //Some code
}

// Form1.h
void button1_click()
{
    abc(textBox1);
}
```

Another way: make `abc` method return type `String^` and set its return value in `Form1` to `textBox1`. Advantage: `abc` doesn't know anything about UI level. Yet another way: events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58cwt3zh.aspx

Comment: Just a question. Might seem silly, though. What is the carat at the end of Form1? This `^`. I have observed it at many places and I can't seem to figure why it is added.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because you haven't specified **whose textBox** that is. It is not enough to `#include` the header file, you need to find a way to communicate with your `Form1` object. You can do this in several ways.

1. Using a global pointer to the instance of your main `Form1` that can be accessed from anywhere,
2. Using a local pointer to the instance of your main `Form1` that is passed around and can be called upon,
3. Providing a friend function that can manipulate the data in the class (not recommended),

I would choose 2.

Comment: I need some sample code to implement #2, can you give me some code?

Comment: Well, have you implemented your `Form1.cpp` file?